# how do I want to take two characters in one text in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string

How do i can take `TV`, `004` and `SBY` word in this text

for example:

```
dim mystring as string
mystring = "TV|004|SBY"
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP should learn how to use Google, before asking such extremely easy (also my teaspoon knows the answer) questions on StackOverflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse the different parts of the string using the [String.Split()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) function.

Here is code example:

```
Dim parts As String() = mystring.Split("|"c)
Console.WriteLine(parts(0)) ' prints TV
Console.WriteLine(parts(1)) ' prints 004
Console.WriteLine(parts(2)) ' prints SBY
```

Comment: Thanks , now i can take this word :)

Comment: @FirdausCan You should accept and upvote this answer if it helped you. It will let future readers know that this is a good answer . :)

Comment: I would recommend that you use a `For Each` loop to write the items within `parts()`, just in case you don't know how my items are in the array.